# How to reloading a modal dialog in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I'm developing a web application which is using a modaldialog(`showModalDialog()`)
. There user have to fill some textfields and as a usual web form if the user have done a mistake the dialog needs to be reloaded. I could able to come up with this by using `location.reload(true);`

But this is not working in IE. Am I missing something or is there any limitation? Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error exactly you are getting in IE? Which version of IE you are using?

Comment: am not getting any error actually Raja, But it's not refreshing the dialog both IE8,IE9.

Comment: Just to get clarification, the textfields are in the modal and when the user submits, you will validate the fields and if there are any errors, you need to show the validation errors in the same modal window. Is that your requirement?

Comment: No Raja, those JavaScript validations are already there and working fine. When loading the dialog, am setting the values of textfields and all input fields from the database. User can edit them and save. If he has done a mistake, he should able to reload the previous values from the database by clicking a Cancel button(which calls `location.reload(true)`). This is the exact scenario :). In IE this function is not working. Somewhere I found that IE modal dialogs are not supporting with `location.reload()`. Is this true? if, any alternative :) ?

Comment: Did you try using window.location.href?? If possible please add your code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Doing the following hassle is because assigning to location.href will not work.  It will only open another window which loads the page from the modal's parent.

First of all, you need create a base tag in your head section, something like

```
<head>
    <base target="_self" />
</head>
```

Then simulate a user click on a link, since this link is just an utility for script to activate the reloading process, you might like to hide it. Let's call this link reload。

```
<a id="reload">reload</a>
```

The script to reload the modal dialog is

```
// Get the link object to simulate user click
var reload = document.getElementById('reload');

// Assign the modal url to the link then click!
reload.href = window.location.href;
reload.click();
```

You should be able to refresh the modal dialog in IE now.